# Select multiple elements from a class model

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have class model like that:

```
orderClass (Order order, Client client, List<Products> productList)
```

Now I want to display the best client for today, I need to select the order and the client and the products from the orderClass after that I need to group it by the client name and calculate the total price for every client.

So I need a query like this:

```cs
from orders in orderClass select(x => x.order)
from clients in orderClass select(x => x.client)
from products in orderClass select(x => x.productList)
group THEALL by client.Name
select new statistic()
{
    Total = THEALL.Sum(x => x.productList.price)
    Id = x.order.Id
    ClientName = x.client.Name
}
.ToList()
.OrderByDescending(x => x.Total)
.Take(1);
```

Comment: You are missing the JOINs

Comment: What have you tried?  What was the result? What was the expected result?  What is your input data?